# What does it mean for a representation to contain a character?

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the statement "The representation $\pi$ contains the trivial character of $N$ if and only if it contains an irreducible representation $\sigma$ of $B$ containing the trivial character of $N$." Does "contains the trivial character of $N$" mean that, if $(\pi, V)$ is the representation, then there is a one-dimensional subspace of $V$ such that the restriction of $\pi$ to $N$ acts trivially? (Here $G = GL_2(F)$ where $F$ is a finite field.)

Comment: I think that's what it means. Without the context, I can't be 100% sure.